# Querying in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb

Just a quick question I hope someone can answer for me.

I have a collection in MongoDB containing 84 thousand documents. The data looks something like this:

[image: Data]

There are several thousand documents containing the word "BOND" as the category name such as this:

[image: More Data]

[image: Even More Data]

And many thousands more...

Currently in MongoDB Compass I am using the following query:

```
{ "Category" : "BOND" }
```

But of course this just returns 1 document that where the Category is BOND.

Can anybody tell me how I can query to find all documents where the field name "Category" contains the word "BOND" within it?

Many thanks,
G

Comment: BTW, This question is surprisingly popular, may be you consider changing its title? Something like "Query by substring in MongoDB" or so?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should use regexp for this, i.e.

```
{ "Category" : /^BOND.*/ }
```

for categories begins with BOND, or

```
{ "Category" : /.*BOND.*/ }
```

for categories contains BOND within

Comment: What if i want to search all the documents from the data in a file. (for the above example)say a file containing a list of oSum values, and i want all the documents matching the those oSum

Comment: @Alexey-Sviridov what can we do for case sensitivity as that is not working ?

Comment: @vibs2006 You can read complete documentation on mongo's $regex here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/  For case insensitivity you can query your collection like { "Category" : /^BOND.*/i } (note i after closing /)

Comment: @ParasSingh I guess you should import your file into a separate collection and then use aggregation with $lookup statement ( see here about $lookup https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ )

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this {'category': /BON?/ }